# JUnit - assertion erros are not propagated

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I am experiencing a certain bug in JUnit/JMock. I am trying to mock a couple of objects and then assert that all expectations is satisfied. I am running a simple test such as :

```
@Test
public void sellingPutOptionProductDoesNotCauseDisclosure() throws PositionVerificationException, DataLoadException, MissingPriceException {
    final OptionProduct optionProduct = setupOptionProduct();
    context.assertIsSatisfied();
}

private OptionProduct setupOptionProduct() {
    final Option optionProduct = context.mock(Option.class);
    context.checking(new Expectations() {
        {
            oneOf(optionProduct).getUnderlyingProduct();
            will(returnValue(new Object()));
        }
    });
    return optionProduct;
}
```

The Option is an object and I am using Mockery like this:

```
context = new Mockery() {
    {
        setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }
};
```

If I run the above test I am gettiing Test passed, where JVM does not terminate and the last print out in console is:

Exception in thread "main"

ANy ideas what  might be causing this?

Comment: It's been a while since I used JMock, but I am not seeing where this should be failing. You are mocking and then verifying without interacting with the mock.

Comment: Stacktrace? Use your debugger and see if you even reach your test function.

Comment: it is hitting it, it gets to assertIsSatisfied, which raises assertionError which gets swallowed

Comment: We need your stacktrace - where is this exception thrown? Also, are you sure you want to be mocking a class? No option to wrap this in an interface?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I just had a similar problem and was able to track down the cause.
Normally, when a method is called that is not part of the expectations, JMock builds the log telling you what was expected that was not found.  In my case, it tried to create that log message after encountering an unexpected call.  The act of creating the log message threw an exception, which got JMock all confused and it reported that the test passed, when it had actually failed.

In my case, the reason that the exception was thrown was that one of the parameters being passed to the "unexpected" function call was an instance of a class.  That class was initialized, in part, with mocked objects.  When JMock was trying to build the error message to tell me about the unexpected invocation, it needed to describe the parameter.  Usually it will say something like `unexpected invocation: myobject.myMethod(param1,param2).`

Because param1, in my case, contained member variables that were mock objects, and the param1 class did not define toString(), the default, Object.toString() was used.

Object.toString() is defined as: `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

My implementation of hashcode for `param1` was using some of those mocked objects.  Those calls on the mocked objects to calculate the hashcode were 'unexpected' invocations themselves, leading JMock to throw an exception when trying to describe the test failure to me.

Unfortunately, instead of recognizing this condition and still reporting as much of the failure as it could, JMock seemed to give up altogether and report the test as passing and offhandedly mention `Exception in thread "main."`

To see if this is happening to you, I recommend you check the parameters involved in the offending function calls.  If any of them are classes, not interfaces, you should see if their use of equals / hashcode / toString use any suspicious calls to member variables that may not be playing nice with how your scenario is being mocked.